# GTK quit dialog box?

Tags: gtk, gtk2

I am using C with GTK to create a dialog box to confirm an exit.

My main window has a quit button -> Dialog box with Yes and No 
Yes should quit the program entirely
No should close the dialog box.

I have tried

```
dialog = gtk_dialog_new();
...
button = gtk_button_new_with_label("Yes");
g_signal_connect(button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(close), NULL);
```

My callback function close is

```
static void close(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data)
{
gtk_main_quit();
}
```

However, my Yes button does not quit anything. Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 4):

`gtk_main_quit()` only leaves the current nested main loop. `gtk_dialog_run()` creates its own nested main loop, so your `gtk_main_quit()` only breaks out of `gtk_dialog_run()`, not out of `gtk_main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `delete-event` of your main window to call your popup when the user tries to close the window. Then in your `on_delete_event` callback, use the value returned by gtk_dialog_run to return the right value. Your `on_delete_event` callback return value controls if the event is propagated and sends the `destroy` signal. Call `gtk_main_quit` from your `on_destroy` callback. Connect your `on_destroy` callback to the `destroy` signal of your main window. Voilà !

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need a main loop for that, you should test what runs return:

```
/* pseudo code*/
if (gtk_dialog_run(dlg) == RESPONSE_YES) {
 gtk_widget_destroy (dlg); # destroys dialog and exits
}
```